# Network interface ionic get ip of device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, ip, emulation

I have a question: How can I get my IP using network interface?

I install plugin using `Cordova` with this command in project folder:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

And this is home.ts:

```
getIpAddress() {
  networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress((ip) => {
    console.log(ip);
  });
}
```

I declare variable out of class.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var networkinterface: any;
```

And this error throws by ionic, and I don't know how to solve.

Please help me.

[image]

And this error throw it by android emulator:

[image]

Comment: cordova doesnt run with ionic serve.. you will need to test with device/emulator

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same problem, i build a view with a button and when i click the button show me an alert, but if i put the ip in subtitule, don't show alert, because network interface does'nt work